# Showing Blank After Adding Some More Text in TextFormFeild Any Solution Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, uitextfield

When I want add More Text in Text Field it showing me blank any solutions for this how can I get solutions
Thank You

[![enter image description here][1]][![enter image description here][2]][2]

Before Add More Text in Text Field
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4roj.png
After Add More Text in Text Field it Showing Blank
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgkWP.png

here is my Code

```
Table(
        border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.black),
        columnWidths: {
          0: FlexColumnWidth(2),
          1: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          2: FlexColumnWidth(1),
          3: FlexColumnWidth(3),
        },
        children: List.generate(bleachingProcessColumn, (index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            return TableRow(children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Chemical",
                    style: tableTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "GPL",
                    style: tableTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "QTY(KG.)",
                    style: tableTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 25.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Process",
                    style: tableTextStyle,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]);
          }
          return TableRow(children: [
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: FormField(builder: (FormFieldState<int> state) {
                return InputDecorator(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: chemicalNameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: FormField(builder: (FormFieldState<int> state) {
                return InputDecorator(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: GPLCrontroller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: FormField(builder: (FormFieldState<int> state) {
                return InputDecorator(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: qtyController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3.0, vertical: 5.0),
              child: FormField(builder: (FormFieldState<int> state) {
                return InputDecorator(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: InputBorder.none,
                  ),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: processController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          ]);
        }),
      ),
```

Comment: Try to add minline and maxline inside textformfield

Comment: Not Working it showing blank before adding more text